# Drive query issue with sync

Tags: android, synchronization, google-drive-android-api

i'm having a problem,i made a query that fetch folder with specific title and it works,

but the problem is that if i delete a folder and remove it  from trash from Firefox or chrome , i get back to my app and query again and the file still present,

the only way that sync from drive is to open the `fileactivitybuilder`and i don't know how it do it.
 Any help?.

```
Query query = new Query.Builder()
            .addFilter(Filters.eq(SearchableField.TITLE, getString(folderName)))
            .build();
    Drive.DriveApi.query(getGoogleApiClient(), query)
            .setResultCallback(metadataCallback);
```

Comment: check this link https://developers.google.com/drive/android/trash which has information on how to delete files and folders in android

Comment: i won't to know how to delete i just want to know ho to sync the drive so the query get all the latest updates

Answer (score 0):

The query method returns results from the local cache to save battery. Use the [`DriveApi.requestSync`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveApi.html#requestSync(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient)) method to update the cache.

Comment: driveapi.requestsync work but i can't use more than 1 time every minute or 2 minutes... is there any workaroud?